# Excel VBA to Only show rows that have a blank cell in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel workbook i have built and I’m trying to improve it. I have custom views that show specific data. 
I need the sheet to look at columns n- x and only show rows that have a blank cell(s).

I have tried a
begin row , end row with chkcol array
 but that isn’t working .

For my specific view of column n-x if all the cells are filled out i don’t need to see it anymore so i want it hidden in that view.

Comment: Some sample data would be useful to understand what you need and the code you have tried and it’s not working so we can start from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what rows you are doing, but this will do all of your usedrange. I didn't test it.

```
Sub SubName()

Dim aCell As Range, WS As Worksheet
    Set WS = ActiveSheet

    For Each aCell In Intersect(WS.UsedRange, WS.Range("n:n")).Cells
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Intersect(WS.Range("N:X"), aCell.EntireRow)) = 0 Then
            aCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            aCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next aCell

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked! I was able to manipulate the code you gave me to work- thanks so much!